# Proof that improper integration works

Tags: integration

I wasn't really sure how to title this, but the way the problem is phrased makes me think of improper integrals so I thought that might be a good title.

Let $f\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}, a <b,$ be Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$. Show that 
$$
\int_a^b f(x) dx = \lim_{T\to b}\int_a^T f(x)dx
$$
I don't really see that there's a whole lot to do here, which is part of my confusion; it feels like it should be harder than this. Let $F$ denote the antiderivative of $f$ which exists by assumption, then apply the fundamental theorem of calculus:
$$
\lim_{T\to b}\int_a^T f(x)dx = \lim_{T\to b } F(T)-F(a) = F(b)-F(a) = \int_a^b f(x) dx 
$$
The only thing that feels a little shaky is justifying $\displaystyle\lim_{T\to b } F(T)=F(b)$. We're only given that $f$ is Riemann integrable, which says nothing about the continuity of the function. What prevents something weird happening at $b$?

Edit: The fundamental theorem on calculus, Rudin version: If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and if there is a differentiable function $F$ on $[a,b]$ such that $F'=f$, then
$$
\int_a^b f(x) dx = F(b)-F(a)
$$

Comment: Part of the fundamental theorem of calculus is that $F$ is continuous if $f$ is Riemann integrable. What is your version of the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: One that I apparently haven't read completely in a while. I'll go read it again.

Comment: Just to make sure that I completely understand what you're saying, by knowing that $f$ is Riemann integrable, we're guaranteed a continuous antiderivative? The version in my calculus textbook only makes an assumption that $f$ is continuous which I don't know to be the case here. What if $f$ is piecewise continuous instead? How do I know what $F$ doesn't have a discontinuity at $b$ (assuming there is one at $f$)?

Comment: Okay. I think I realized where I went wrong. We have specifically that $F'=f$, which implies that we have a differentiable function. But differentiability implies continuity, so $F$ must be continuous, and so we get that $\lim_{T\to b} F(T)=F(b)$.

Comment: No, that's not it. Define $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t) \, dt$. If $f$ is integrable, then the FTC tells you that $F$ is continuous. If $f$ is continuous, then the FTC tells you that $F$ is differentiable. You are not granted this second assumption here. As @lhf pointed out, this depends on the version of the FTC that you learned.

Comment: Okay. I'm going to copy the version of the FTC that is given in Rudin since that is the text used in our analysis course. Given that, can someone help me fix my proof?

Comment: @chris: I'm going to post a bigger answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rudin there are two relevant theorems. Here is one of them:

> **6.20 Theorem** Let $f$ be Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$. For $a \le x \le b$, put $$F(x)=\int_a^x f(t) \, dt.$$ Then $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$; furthermore, if $f$ is continuous at a point $x_0$ of $[a,b]$, then $F$ is differentiable at $x_0$, and $$F'(x_0)=f(x_0).$$

You have already stated the other theorem (6.21) in your edit, but you do not need that theorem to answer your question. (In fact, it does not apply here since $f$ may not be continuous.) If $f$ is Riemann integrable then $F$ (as defined in Theorem 6.20) is continuous on $[a,b]$. Then $\lim_{x \rightarrow b} F(x) = F(b)$, i.e. $$\lim_{x \rightarrow b} \int_a^x f(t) \, dt = \int_a^b f(t) \, dt.$$

Your proof states "Let $F$ denote the antiderivative of $f$ which exists by assumption", which is simply not true!

Comment: Thank you. I think what I really need to do is lay out all of the theorems that I have at my disposal and get everything organized. I completely forgot this existed, and as you noted, the FTC isn't particularly useful here, precisely because of objections that I noted earlier. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: How do we justify the final step, given that $F$ may not be an antiderivative of $f$? The equality $\int_a^b f = F(b) -F(a)$ assumes $F$ is an antiderivative, which we don't have here.